# (JGraph/mxGraph) Return selected cells

Tags: java, jgraph, mxgraph

So after the user selected a few cells and pressed a button, I need to have those cells properties like position, size and stuff. So how do I make a method that'll only return me the cells that the user selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graph.getSelectionCells() should work

Comment: Had no idea it was so simple. Thanks bro, I'm new to this library and can't find useful info :/